# How to login inside a AWS server & do some maintenance on it using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, devops

I need to login inside a AWS Linux server, then create a folder, add some ownership on it and lastly restart tomcat.
I know that I should be using Ansible or any config mgmt tool & that's easy way.. but out of curiosity I want to do it using Python.
So basically, the steps that need to be followed are:

1. Login to Machine
2. mkdir /mnt/some_new_folder
3. Give permissions, chown tomcat7:tomcat7 /mnt/some_new_folder
4. Lastly restart tomcat: sudo service tomcat7 restart
5. Lastly logout

Is it possible to do all this via Python script ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, using paramiko library you can ssh to remote machine and perform required operations.

Comment: Please do not use excessive question marks as it makes the question look like the author is not seriously looking help and this may discourage people answering your question. Keep your language professional.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa okay. I hope this ones good

Comment: @NishantSingh: better :) No worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With open source tools like Python everything is possible. Only your knowledge sets the limit.

I would suggest using [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) module which allows easy execution of remote commands over SSH.

[sh + SSH tutorial](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/tutorials/2-interacting_with_processes.html?highlight=ssh).

You can use it like:

```
 import sh

 print(sh.ssh("username@example.com", "mkdir /foo/bar"))
```

[First you need to setup proper SSH keys and SSH agent](https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/10/24/ssh-key-and-passwordless-login-basics-for-developers/).